# Select fields thats not exist in JSON Spark-Json Dataset

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Java-Spark and I have JSON that looks like this:

```
{
      "name": "myname",
       "age":"35"
}
```

Or:

```
{
    "name": "myname",
    "age":"35",
    "country":"US"
}
```

That I read to `Dataset` as follows:

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().json(jsonSet);
Dataset<Row> dfSelect = df.select(cols);//Where cols is Column[]
```

The array `cols` contain the columns `name`, `age` and `country` but sometimes the JSON doesn't contain the `country` field and `df.select(cols)` throws an exception.

How can I select to all fields even if the field doesn't exist in the JSON file?

Comment: You can try defining a static schema while reading the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As been suggested in a comment by philantrovert, you can use a predefined schema when reading the json file. If the column do not exist in the json file, all the values will simply be `null`. It can be done in Java as follows:

```
List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("age", DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("country", DataTypes.StringType, true));
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().schema(schema).json(jsonSet);
```

Column data types can be changed as needed in the schema. There is no need to do the `select` with the columns afterwards since `df` already contains the wanted columns.

Comment: @YaKo: For nested columns you still have to use either `select` or `withColumn` to flatten the dataframe schema. An example of how the schema should be created in that situation can be seen for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315784/created-a-nested-schema-in-apache-spark-sql

Comment: After I created the schema and when I'm make the select(cols) thats still throws exception because Its cannot found the column

Comment: @YaKo: If you have a nested JSON (as indicated by your comment) you need to provide a nested schema when reading. Can you try to use `printSchema()` before the select to check so all columns are present?

Comment: @Shido, Thank you!!

Comment: @YaKo: No problems, happy to help :)